# errors in uploading to app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to submit my finished app in the apple app store and this is the errors i got

1. Apple's web service operation was not successful
2. Unable to authenticate the `package: 854334543.itmsp`
3. `ERROR ITMS-9000:"Invalid Provisioning Profile.` The provisioning profile included in the bundle name `{Bundle name}[Payload/bundle name}`is invalid. [Missing code signing certificate].
4. Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics

what's seems to be the problem here?

Comment: check the provisioning profile u created, that is not proper what error shows

Comment: please given correct bundle Id and corresponding provision of distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says the reason. You can change provisioning profile from **code signing** option.

[image]

Form the above image change you provisioning profile and set it to desired one.